# how to know when a new Antivirus has installed on windows

Tags: c#, windows, registry, antivirus

I want to monitor the event of a new Antivirus installation , 
currently what I have in mind is listen to change in the Uninstall registry folder and then compare the new application name with a list of known Antiviruses.

I want to improve it by being more specific , is there other resource I can monitor in order to know when a new Antivirus has installed? for example some registry that new Antivirus have to edit in order to be marked as an active Antivirus etc.

Thank you for your help

Comment: there's too many kind of and vendors for antivirus. unless you have a whole lot of database that helps to detect each and every versions of them, it's probably impossible to do. Besides, what have you done so far? you need to ask a more specific question that is related of programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registry is not the best way. The information you want is usually exposed through the WMI.

Since you haven't specify in tags what language you're using, here's [the link to the VBScript example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/05/12/how-to-get-antivirus-information-with-wmi-vbscript.aspx). Beware that on 64 bit OSes there're effectively 2 WMIs, 32 bits and 64 bits.

If you want your software to react instantly, [WscRegisterForChanges API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows you to be notified when the AV is started or stopped.

Comment: I do know I can get the details from the WMI , 
I guess WscRegisterForChanges is what I need , I'll look into it.
Thank you.